# Apache OFBiz: Difference between <entity-condition> and <entity-and>?

Tags: xml, ofbiz

i am new to OFBiz and while reading eBook I'm unable differentiate between these two method of accessing data from database.and i google it but i did not find suitable explanation for same.thanks in advance for help.

```
<entity-condition>
  <field-map value="">
</entity-condition>

<entity-and>
 <field-map value="">
</entity-and>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entity-and is used to fetch data from database where multiple primary keys required (composite PK) to fetch single record and you want all records which matches any field ie queries like

```
select * from table where Colname=abc;
```

On entity-condition you can write multiple entity-condition experations with 'AND'/'OR' clause.

And the error is your using field map inside entity-condition use entity-expr

```
 <entity-condition list="anyList" entity-name="Table">
   <condition-expr field-name="colName1" from-field="variable1"/>
   <condition-expr field-name="colName2" from-field="variable2"/>
 </entity-condition>
```